# Filterable: true is not available in angular version of Kendo UI Pivot Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to add filters to the pivot grid as below. Please help me to implement filter option as below by using Kendo UI Angular.

This is the code I'm using for pivot grid and don't know where to add the property to enable the filter.

```
<kendo-pivotgrid [kendoPivotLocalBinding]="timingTableData" [dimensions]="dimensions" [measures]="measures"
  [rowAxes]="rows" [columnAxes]="columns" [measureAxes]="defaultMeasureAxes">
</kendo-pivotgrid>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VqBC.png)

I'm trying to add filters for kendo UI pivot grid in angular 14.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define the [filter](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/pivotgrid/api/PivotLocalBindingDirective/#toc-filter) property and provide a [FilterDescriptor](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/data-query/api/FilterDescriptor/) for the filtering to work. For more details you can refer to our documentation:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/pivotgrid/filtering/

Setting the filter property to **true** isn't a valid option in the case of the PivotGrid, but other components like the Grid will work.